# creating time to improvement of +1 variable in r?

Tags: r

I want to create a "time to improvement of +1" variable I have a longitudinal in a long format at baseline, 3, 6 and 9 months. How do I go about it in r? The improvement from the baseline.
The data is like this:

```
sno time WHZ
1    0   -0.5
1    3    1.4
1    6   -0.7
1    9    2.2
2    0   -0.63
2    3    0.7
2    6   -2.64
2    9    2.1
```

expected output

```
sno time WHZ      impr   First time to imp
1    0   -0.5      0              3
1    3    1.4      1.9            3
1    6   -0.7     -0.2            3
1    9    2.2      2.7            3
2    0   -0.63     0              3
2    3    0.7       1.33          3
2    6   -2.64    -2.01           3
2    9    2.1        2.73         3
```

Codes I was trying to use to first create the improvement variable:

```
library(dplyr)    
data %>%    
  group_by(sno)%>%    
  mutate(ImprvWHZ = data$WHZ - lag(data$WHZ, default = data$WHZ[1]))
```

Comment: Hi! Can you show us the expected output?And possibily what you've tired?

Comment: sno time WHZ impr   First time to imp
1    0   -0.5      0                   3
1    3    1.4      1.9                3
1    6   -0.7     -0.2               3
1    9    2.2      2.7                3
2    0   -0.63     0                  3
2    3    0.7       1.33             3
2    6   -2.64    -2.01             3
2    9    2.1        2.73            3

Comment: First i was trying to create the improvement variable which could not work. I was using this codes: library(dplyr)
FPdata %>%
arrange(desc(time), desc(sno)) %>% 
group_by(sno)%>%
mutate(ImprvWHZ=FPdata$WHZ-lag(FPdata$WHZ,default=0))                Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `ImprvWHZ` must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 1152

Comment: You must post the expected output **in the question**, not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(sno) %>%
  mutate(Improv = WHZ - WHZ[1],
         TimeToImprov = ifelse(Improv > 1, time - time[1], NA))
## A tibble: 8 x 5
## Groups:   sno [2]
#    sno  time   WHZ Improv TimeToImprov
#  <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>        <int>
#1     1     0 -0.5   0               NA
#2     1     3  1.4   1.9              3
#3     1     6 -0.7  -0.200           NA
#4     1     9  2.2   2.7              9
#5     2     0 -0.63  0               NA
#6     2     3  0.7   1.33             3
#7     2     6 -2.64 -2.01            NA
#8     2     9  2.1   2.73             9
```

And here is a base R solution.

```
res <- lapply(split(dat, dat$sno), function(DF){
  DF$Improv <- DF$WHZ - DF$WHZ[1]
  DF$TimeToImprov <- ifelse(DF$Improv > 1, DF$time - DF$time[1], NA)
  DF
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
row.names(res) <- NULL

res
#  sno time   WHZ Improv TimeToImprov
#1   1    0 -0.50   0.00           NA
#2   1    3  1.40   1.90            3
#3   1    6 -0.70  -0.20           NA
#4   1    9  2.20   2.70            9
#5   2    0 -0.63   0.00           NA
#6   2    3  0.70   1.33            3
#7   2    6 -2.64  -2.01           NA
#8   2    9  2.10   2.73            9
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
sno time WHZ
1    0   -0.5
1    3    1.4
1    6   -0.7
1    9    2.2
2    0   -0.63
2    3    0.7
2    6   -2.64
2    9    2.1                  
", header = TRUE)
```